# zsh global alias pipe to file and open file in vim gets stuck

Tags: vim, zsh

I wish to have a global alias that redirects output and open in vim. It used to work like this

```
alias -g V=' > /tmp/vim-tmp && vim /tmp/vim-tmp '
```

but stopped working(e.g: `ls V`), the terminal gets stuck and only by CTRL-c I get my prompt back, but the file `/tmp/vim-tmp` doesn't get written to.

Opening in less works `alias -g V=' > /tmp/vim-tmp && less /tmp/vim-tmp '` but that's not what I want.

Doing the same straight from terminal works `ls > /tmp/vim-tmp && vim /tmp/vim-tmp`. All my other global aliases work and if I do `alias -g V=' > /tmp/vim-tmp'` the file `/tmp/vim-tmp` gets properly written to. I'm using nvim but get the same result with regular vim.

Any ideas how to properly setup such a global alias?

I'm working with zsh 5.3.1(same effect with zsh 5.2), neovim v0.2.2(same effect with vim 8.0), macos SIERRA 10.12.2 and iterm2 3.0.4(same effect with terminal 2.7.1)

Comment: It could come from you zshrc. Try with a fresh one and if it works use dichotomy to find what's wrong in your zshrc. In mine enabling *fasd* makes your alias stop working.

Comment: And what if you press *:q<CR>* while it is stuck?

Comment: @rools enabling fasd is indeed the problem. I don't know about `:q<CR>` but it's pointless to go checking it know since I solved my problem already(as mentioned in the answer I gave). thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh I did not see your answer! I did not think it was the same problem as me, since for me with fasd without any patch `alias -g V="| vim -"` works. You should mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I know, stackoverflow demands a 24 hours wait before I can accept my own answer.

Comment: Okay, I am not smart enough to answer my own question so quickly, so I never saw this limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out. I'm using [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) plugin(and absolutely love it), but it was the one screwing me up. Fasd registers to zsh preexec hook with function `_fasd_preexec` and that's where the command was getting stuck for my global alias. [I've added a hack of my own to their source code to stop the problem. I've opened and issue with them.](https://github.com/clvv/fasd/issues/120)

Answer (score 2):

You can write a global alias using standard input directly:

```
alias -g V="| vim -"
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. I have the exact same effect of the terminal getting stuck. If it were to work though it would have the side effect of putting me into an unnamed buffer that has been modified forcing me to save or `q!` to exit vim which is not what I was bargaining for.

Comment: See my new comment on your post.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather code a global function (in `.zshrc` for instance)

```
function my_funct() {
  $1 > /tmp/vim-tmp && vim /tmp/vim-tmp;
}
```

then call it with:

```
$ my_funct ls
```

You could add more tests to `my_funct` to check whether `$1` exists

Comment: that's not what I need. You see, many times I only remember that I want to see the result in vim when I finished typing or my command may be something long `git log ME --pretty=oneline --grep='WEED- @ home | chaos' V`, etc. I used to love my `V` alias and its very disturbing that it doesn't work anymore